# Why is my Blogger subdomain appearing in URLs on my page instead of my custom domain?

Tags: domains, url, subdomain, blogger, nameserver

Recently I bought a new domain (`example.com`) and pointed it to my blogger account. My domain is working well.

But the problem is my sitemap contains the `http://subdomain.blogspot.com` which is the original blog that I actually created, instead of my custom domain.

Also when I copy a URL from my page, I'm getting `http://subdomain.blogspot.com/some-xyz`.

Why do URLs in my blog still have the blogspot subdomain in them, instead of my custom domain? I had tried changing templates, but this didn't resolve the issue.

Update:

I've reset the DNS to default and tried again. 
Now the issue is solved. It will be good if someone finds out what happened before so that this will not repeat again.

Comment: We'll have to know a little more information about what steps you took so far. Can you let us know what those were from [here](https://support.google.com/blogger/troubleshooter/1233381?hl=en)?

Comment: purchased a domain.

created CNAME  "www" and Destination "ghs.google.com." 

Also entered A-records,  in the "A" section. with following IPs.
216.239.32.21
216.239.34.21
216.239.36.21
216.239.38.21

Comment: Just to clarify, you waited 24 hours (in step 11) and your custom domain is resolving to your blog, but you're concerned because links in your page still contain the subdomain instead of your custom domain?

Comment: Yes. I don't have any problem with the resolving. I'm concerned with the links in the site. When I copy a link, I'm getting "http://subdomain.blogspot.com/post-url" instead of "http://example.com/post-url". To be specific I'm using a domain with ".in" extension

Comment: I further clarified this for you. The `.in` extension shouldn't be a factor if your domain is pointed to your Blogger site correctly and you followed the rest of the steps there. Note that we use `example.com` as a generic domain here since it's meant for that purpose, but users can see this from your comment above.

Comment: You have to add second CNAME as well. Blogger provide two CNAME, one is common to all blogger, which you already added ghs.google.com, and second one is different for all blogger.

Comment: Maybe it is redirected because of .htaccess rule, can you confirm you don't have any rows in your .htaccess file looking like this : `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com\.` basically this will check if the domain name is www.example.com and if it isn't it will redirect it to it. In addition you can post your htaccess file and we can check it, also do not provide information like your real IP address and website address because nobody would need it to help you.

Comment: Knifer@Blogger don't support htaccess.

Comment: @prathapareddy I'd suggest adding what you did in an answer below and accept that, or letting MaryC.fromNZ know that helped by accepting her answer.

Answer (score 1):

As well as setting up the CNAME and ANAME records mentioned in the comments, you also need to publish your blog to the custom domain.

Go to the **Settings > Basic** tab, and follow the options under the **Publishing** section.   This is where you may get the 2nd CNAME record that needs to be added for validation.

Comment: I've added the second Cname record also.